# Missing these required gems: troelskn-handsoap SOAP Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, handsoap

I followed the instructions in the Handsoap wiki.

However, when I try to run my application I get this error:

> Missing these required gems:
>   troelskn-handsoap

And if I run:

> gem install troelskn-handsoap

I get:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem
>   'troelskn' (>= 0) in any repository

What am I missing?

Thx.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The gem has been renamed - It's now simply named `handsoap`. Install it from gemcutter:

```
gem sources -a http://gemcutter.org
sudo gem install handsoap curb nokogiri
```

The canonical repository for Handsoap is now on https://github.com/unwire/handsoap